# fasttext' has no attribute 'train_supervised' on Windows 10

Tags: python, fasttext

I installed fasttext manually and also installing it using pip install. But
when I use this code
`model = fastText.train_supervised(input=training_data_path, **hyper_params)`

**output**: No module named 'fastText'

Also this code:
`model = fasttext.train_supervised(input=training_data_path, **hyper_params)`

**output**: fasttext' has no attribute 'train_supervised'

I already installed and follow the documentation still no fix

Comment: Please share the output of `dir (fasttext)`

Comment: @anakin87 "C:\Users\Akio\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\fasttext"

Comment: I mean in python: `import fasttext` then `dir (fasttext)`

Comment: @anakin87 I Already fix it by Renaming the fasttext folder into fastText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied the folder named fasttext in anaconda site-packages dir and paste it in site-packages of Python dir and renaming it by:

orig name: "fasttext"

changes: "fastText"